# Boto3 Client get_object .read() is not reading files(images) from S3 bucket and causing timeout when used in AWS lambda with Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to access images stored in an AWS S3 bucket using Lambda function. I am using Python 3.9 runtime.
The code to read images from the S3 bucket is as follows:

```
import json
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(<efs storage mount path>)
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import model_from_json
import cv2
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def open_images(img1_path_in_bucket, img2_path_in_bucket):
    print('opening images')
    print(img1_path_in_bucket)
    print(img2_path_in_bucket)
    print(s3)    
    file_obj1 = s3.get_object(Bucket=<bucket_name>, Key=img1)
    print(file_obj1)
    file_content1 = file_obj1["Body"].read()
    print('Image 1 content get complete')
    img1 = np.asarray(bytearray(file_content1))
    print('image1 read')
    file_obj2 = s3.get_object(Bucket=<bucket_name>, Key=img2)
    file_content2 = file_obj2["Body"].read()
    img2 = np.asarray(bytearray(file_content2))
    print('images read')
    return(img1, img2)
```

The problem is that the Lambda function is timing out. 8 out of 10 times it will timeout and on the other 2 times it would randomly give the correct response (The only time it works is when there are some new edits to the code). I have kept the timeout time as 180 seconds and when the Lambda function runs successfully it usually takes around 25-40 seconds to give a complete response.

I also want to mention that images from the same S3 bucket are accessible when I edit and run the code in a AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instance.

I have ruled out the VPC, security groups, permissions as possible issues because the Lambda function sometimes runs successfully and retrieves the images.

When the Lambda function runs successfully and the images are retrieved from the S3 bucket, I get the following trace:

**Function Logs**

```
opening images
img1_path_in_bucket/1594029935670-1594029928375.jpg
img2_path_in_bucket/1594029935670-1594029928375.jpg
"botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f606b3e1b20"
```

```js
{
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': 'DSBC9XC464QGAXY0',
    'HostId': 'h8nYmrO9X6D30Tme0O03ADMqVWLfYFsglbrTUksZeV8F0DFgvueNVy+v0WaVTiAtckDKd4KbisY=',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'x-amz-id-2': 'h8nYmrO9X6D30Tme0O03ADMqVWLfYFsglbrTUksZeV8F0DFgvueNVy+v0WaVTiAtckDKd4KbisY=',
      'x-amz-request-id': 'DSBC9XC464QGAXY0',
      'date': 'Wed, 05 Oct 2022 16:07:17 GMT',
      'last-modified': 'Mon, 06 Jul 2020 10:05:38 GMT',
      'etag': '"8773fa3be96ffbdb156d5491ae800bf7"',
      'x-amz-meta-fieldname': 'image',
      'x-amz-version-id': 'null',
      'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
      'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
      'server': 'AmazonS3',
      'content-length': '214592'
    },
    'RetryAttempts': 0
  },
  'AcceptRanges': 'bytes',
  'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 10, 5, 38, tzinfo = tzutc()),
  'ContentLength': 214592,
  'ETag': '"8773fa3be96ffbdb156d5491ae800bf7"',
  'VersionId': 'null',
  'ContentType': 'image/jpeg',
  'Metadata': {
    'fieldname': 'image'
  },
  'Body': < botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f6068651a60 >
}
```

```
Image 1 content get complete
image1 read
images read
```

And when the Lambda function times out, it gives the following trace:

```
START RequestId: 21286317-0827-42ee-80f6-4506dc8b925d Version: $LATEST
opening images
profile-images/1000X1000/1594029935670-1594029928375.jpg
profile-images/1000X1000/1594029935670-1594029928375.jpg
"botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7febf82dcb20"
END RequestId: 21286317-0827-42ee-80f6-4506dc8b925d
REPORT RequestId: 21286317-0827-42ee-80f6-4506dc8b925d  Duration: 180213.23 ms  Billed 
Duration: 180000 ms Memory Size: 10000 MB   Max Memory Used: 2295 MB    
2022-10-05T20:08:43.483Z 21286317-0827-42ee-80f6-4506dc8b925d Task timed out after 
180.21 seconds
```

It can be seen that it is getting stuck at the line `file_content1 = file_obj1["Body"].read()`

What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like you configured the Lambda function to connect to a VPC. Does it need to be in your VPC (for EFS)?

Comment: Yes it does. The lambda function and the EFS are on the same VPC and share the same security groups

Comment: The Lambda function is configured to connect to multiple subnets. Make sure they are all the same type of subnet (typically private) with equivalent network routing to EFS. And increase the Lambda function's RAM size (so it gets more CPU and network bandwidth) then re-test. Your Lambda function is importing large Python packages during cold start.

Comment: I have already made sure that both efs and lambda share the same subnets. The RAM size is 10000Mbs and when the function is successful, it is only using ~2800-3000Mbs of RAM.

Comment: Going back to the original diagnostics you provided, I think you're saying that the code works correctly when the Lambda function cold starts (right after you've updated the code) but it fails for warm starts. The code you've posted doesn't actually include the Lambda function handler. Can you add the missing code so that we can see what the difference is between cold and warm start?